# Как создать частную 4g сеть

Tags: подсети, wimax, сеть

Есть желание раздавать интернет через 4g. Какое конкретно оборудование для этого необходимо? Погуглил эту тему, внятных ответов нигде не нашел. Сеть планируется вида:

сервер->точка доступа (n)->клиентыточки доступа могут быть взаимосвязаны и передавать данные по цепочке в зависимости от загруженности. клиенты не привязаны к точкам доступа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А какую 4G - LTE, WiMAX. Ну впрочем вопрос риторический, там базовая станция от 40 000$.Будете брать? Да вот [для примера](http://www.forum4g.ru/showthread.php?t=435)

Comment: почитал про базовую станцию, понял что деньги за аппарат это не самая большая проблема (